# how to by pass the nginx setting on elastic beanstalk for /assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, assets

Stack: Elastic Bean, Ruby 2.1, Puma, Rails 3

EB default config for nginx is directing /assets request to location: app_path/public/assets. We need to direct /assets as requests to the app like say myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/products. In other words, our app has assets table in db, Asset model and routes.rb defines assets resource.

I tried the hook/config below, but no luck. It is giving sigterm error.

```
# .ebextensions/z_assets.conf

files:
"/etc/nginx/conf.d/z_assets.conf":
  mode: "000755"
  owner: root
  group: root  
  content: |   
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier
      location /assets {
        proxy_pass http://my_app/assets; 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
    }
```

Comment: why do you think nginx is messing with your routes? nginx is only a proxy so it obeys whatever your rails server (puma) does.

Comment: yes it does mess up and we have to add 
  location ^~ assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

to make the static assets work. 

I am also trying to find a proper way to do this